# How do I constraint my import "bulma/css/bulma.min.css" to just one file in my REACT APP?

Tags: reactjs, bulma

Hello I am creating a REACT application with a team and I am in charge of a specific page. I decided to use the Bulma framework to create my page called Catalog.js and when I connected my page to the rest of my app the bulma import statement in Catalog.js affects the styling of the whole app in general.

How do I constrain bulma to just Catalog.js?

I have tried a multitude of things but none work correctly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you imported the css file in the `Catalog.js` file?